# Mysql connection qt 5.4

Tags: qt

I want to connect to a mysql database from qt 5.4 linux ubuntu os, this is my code:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtSql/QSql>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDriver>
#include <QtSql/QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>

Server::Server()
{
//Data base
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase( "QMYSQL" );

    qDebug() <<db.lastError().text();

    db.setHostName( "localhost" );
    db.setDatabaseName( "clientdb" );

    db.setUserName( "root" );
    db.setPassword( "" );

    if(!db.open())
      qDebug() << "No database connection!!" ;
    else
      qDebug() << "Database connected" ;

  /* QSqlQuery qry(db);

    qry.prepare( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clients (id INTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, firstname VARCHAR(30))" );
    if( !qry.exec() )
        qDebug() << qry.lastError();
    else
        qDebug() << "Table created" ;
  */

 //  qry.prepare("INSERT INTO clients (id) VALUES (1)" );


  db.close();
 }
```

The problem is that the db.open() returns false, so the problem source is this line **QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase( "QMYSQL" )** .
I had earlier the error that says cannot load the MYSQL driver, but I solved this problem. 
I tried to change the MYSQL driver to SQLITE driver, and suprisingly it worked!!
I don't know what's wrong with this MYSQL driver!!

Please I really need your help, I spent 9 hours googling looking for solutions, I've tried everything and no results.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: does your database `clientdb` exist?

Comment: call `QSqlDatabase::lastError` after opening

Answer (score 0):

Actually that was the problem. I didn't know I was supposed to create the database first before using this
`db.setDatabaseName( "clientdb" );`.
Thanks a lot!!